# JQuery - Why can't I get alert() popping up?

Tags: jquery

I started learning JQUery recently.
Although I already managed to pop up alerts yesterday, suddenly I fail.

```js
$("circle").click(function(){
    alert("Gi");
});
```

```css
#circle{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="circle">

</div>
```

So when I click on my circle, nothing happens (chrome browser).
What am I missing here?

Comment: Voting to close this question as a "typo" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a `#` in the selector to get an element by his `id`;

```js
$("#circle").click(function(){
    alert("Gi");
});
```

```css
#circle{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="circle">

</div>
```

[jQuery ID Selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the id char selector `#`.

Try :

```
    $("#circle").click(function(){
```